# Complex number polar forms

Tags: complex-numbers

***$(1-i\sqrt{3})^{50}$ in the form x + iy***

I have tried this out but seem to be missing something

Comment: Please share what have you tried

Comment: The form $x+iy$ is not polar form. Nor is $(1-i \sqrt(3))^{50}.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First show $(1-i \sqrt(3))^6=64$ and then use $50=6 \cdot 8+2.$

Answer (score 0):

The polar form of a complex number $z=a+bi$ is $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$.

$$\left(1-i\sqrt{3}\right)^{50}=2^{50} \cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{50}$$

$$=2^{50}\left(\cos \left(\frac{-\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin \left(\frac{-\pi}{3}\right)\right)^{50}$$

Using [De moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

$$=2^{50}\left(\cos \left(\frac{-50\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin \left(\frac{-50\pi}{3}\right)\right)$$

In x+iy format, [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281-i%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%29%5E%7B50%7D) gets $-562949953421312 - 562949953421312 i \sqrt{3}$